# GXT 2.3 : Combobox : tooltip on hover

Tags: gwt, extjs, combobox, gxt

I'm using GWT 2.3.0 and Sencha EXT 2.3.1. I can not upgrade due to software requirements.

I've got a combobox, in a form, with some values.
A few of these values cannont be entirely displayer because the width of the combobox is too short. But I'm not allowed to enlarge this field.

Is there a solution to add a tooltip, or show the entire value when you are hovering the value in the list ?
Or make the displayed list larger than the display field ?

Thx,
Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple. Sencha Gxt 2.3 Examples has already provide a quite good example on how to add tooltip to combobox. But I will post it again for you in here, so here it goes:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.setSpacing(10);

    ListStore<State> states = new ListStore<State>();
    states.add(getStates());

    ComboBox<State> combo = new ComboBox<State>();
    combo.setEmptyText("Select a state...");
    combo.setDisplayField("name");
    combo.setTemplate(getTemplate());
    combo.setWidth(150);
    combo.setStore(states);
    combo.setTypeAhead(true);
    combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
    vp.add(combo);  

    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
}
private native String getTemplate() /*-{
    return [
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-combo-list-item" qtip="{slogan}" qtitle="State Slogan">{name}</div>',
            '</tpl>' ].join("");
}-*/;
```

The key is to use a template to render the combobox value with qtip added to each one of the value div. You can read more about it in [here](http://javadox.com/com.extjs/gxt/2.3.0-gwt17/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/tips/QuickTip.html)
If you want to see the result, it will looks like in sencha gxt 2 examples in [here](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#combobox), just take a look at the second combobox, it will show you tooltip every time you hover the combobox item.
That's it, hope it will help you. Thanks & Regards.